# How to get value of input in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get a value of input to use below, how to do that?
I tried to like this but error says

> Undefined variable: name

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
</div>


<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    @php
       $nameValue=$_GET['name'];
    @endphp
    <input id="name2" type="text" name="name2" value="{{$nameValue}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: show us your controller code

Comment: Your inputs are missing opening <

Comment: I try to do that only in .blade.php without controller

Comment: execute this line ` dd($_GET)`

Comment: Why do this in a view? Does `$nameValue = $request->get('name');` do it?

Comment: I need to auto fill the input field name2

Comment: just dont forget blade.php are being rendered in server not client side. And dont do this short answer.

Answer (score 6):

You have to be aware that your input-values (here "name") ist only available after submitting the form.

If you want to access the form-values before submitting you should take a look at VueJS or any other frontend-framework (React, Angular). Or simply use jQuery.

Therefor you have to use JavaScript if you want to use the input-value before submitting.

Like the others said in the comments, you can access your form-values within your controller and then pass it to your view.

For example (from the documentation):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function formSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');

        return view('form', ['name' => $name])
    }
}
```

Now you can use the value within your view:

```
<input id="name2" type="text" name="name2" value="{{$name}}">
```

Another possibility would be to "by-pass" your controller and return your view directly from your routes.php:

```
Route::get('/form-submit', function(){
    return view('form');
});
```

But I'm not sure if this is working and you could access $_GET/$_PSOT directly without using Laravels Request.

Comment: @OP tries "to do that only in .blade.php without controller"

Answer (score 5):

```
$nameValue=Request::input('name')
```

From the blade template you can access the request parameters with the `Request` facade, you can also print it directly:

```
{{Request::input('name')}}
```

In latest versions you can also use:

```
{{request()->input('name')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get inputs array from Request class:

```
Request::all()['your_input']
```

Also you can check if that input you want is exists not:

```
@isset(Request::all()['your_input'])
     {{-- your input existed --}}
@else
     {{-- your input does not existed --}}
@endisset
```